# Setting and deleting a layout from a class

Tags: ios, xcode

I got a class named Layout, and in this class there are some functions like, setTextView, etc. In my FirstViewController I then need to set that layout on the viewcontroller.

My Layout.m for example looks like this:

```
-(UITextView*) setTextView{

UITextView *textView1 =[[UITextView alloc]init];
textView1.frame=CGRectMake(0,50,282,210);
textView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[textView1 setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];

return textView1;
}
```

And in my FirstViewController.m I got something like:

```
Layout *test;
UITextView *textView1 = [test setTextView];
[self.view addSubview:textView1];
[textView1 removeFromSuperview];
test = nil;
```

But this isn't working, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... that code doesn't make much sense. You are doing `[test setTextView];`, that is, sending a message to an object named `test` and in the next line you define that object as `Layout`.

Then you are removing that test object from its superview, but you never added it to any view (not in the code shown anyway)

I'm going to take a wild guess here, but I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
Layout* test = [[Layout alloc] init]; //You should be calling here whatever initialization method this class has
UITextView *textView1 = [text setTextView];

[self.view addSubview:textView1];

test = nil;
```

Still I'm not sure on what your are trying to accomplish here. Maybe if you try to explain that I can help you better.

Comment: Good answer, just remember to release "test" at the end or define it with autorelease :)

Comment: My code is a little messed up there, normally it was something like this:
    Layout *test;

    UITextView *textView1 = [test setTextView];

    [self.view addSubview:textView1];

    [textView1 removeFromSuperview];

    test = nil;

I have edited it in my original post.

Comment: Now it seems to work, but can I just use [[Layout alloc] init]; are do I really need to create an own init method?

Comment: Don't need to release "test" if he's using ARC. And since it seems he's new to this, he should be using ARC for sure.

Comment: You have to init the class somehow. Either by using some inherited method or creating your own that calls the superclass initialization method. I recommend you take a look at Standford CS193p classes in iTunes University: https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/coding-together-developing/id593208016

Comment: And yes I'm using ARC, do I still need to set test on nil when using ARC?

Comment: That depends on the rest of your code. But it's good practice if you are not using test anymore.

Comment: If I want to use the interface builder do I need to use IBOutlet?

Comment: You should ask another question for that or take a look at some tutorials. But yes, you design it in interface builder (storyboard in new versions of xcode) and wire it up with your code. The IBOutlet will be created automatically.